# Force spring to start request

Tags: spring, thrift

is there way to force spring to start new request from some point of code?

The reason beyond it is, that I am replacing communication from Rest to Thrift, but there are beans with request scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by overriding Request Scope using SimpleThreadScope.